# Android, Cicerone. Is it possible to implement cicerone with bottom navigation and Single Activity approach?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, bottomnavigationview, android-navigation

I'm using cicerone and single activity approach. When the application starts, the first three seconds I'm showing splash fragment inside my activity and so redirect to home fragment. Now I need to add to my application bottom navigation. Is it possible to add bottom navigation using single activity approach and cicerone. Or will I have to add another activity for the holding bottom navigation ?

Unfortunately, I could not find examples of projects with cicerone, single activity and bottom navigation.

My main goal is to save single activity, please tell me if it is possible to achieve this ?

Comment: here is a project by creator of cicerone: https://gitlab.com/terrakok/gitlab-client/-/tree/develop/app

sadly its MVP pattern( good luck